# Snowflake: How to perform CTAS or copy data from table x to y with constraints and default values involved?

Tags: sql, database, copy, clone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I usually copy data from one table to another using CTAS or CLONE.
The problem is that I not only have to rename same columns on the target, but I also need to:

1. define constraints (which are OK in an alter table, add constraint)
2. Alter column and SET NOT Null, for example
3. Define DEFAULT values thar are *not* sequences...thus SF dosn't support his.

So, how can this be accomplish if I can't even add a column with default? My idea was to CTAS and then alter table to add columns defaults, pks and other constraints, but it fails on defaults ...

If I do a plain CTAS I'm able to rename columns, but can't keep/change the constraints and defaults, can I?

Is there a way to achieve this? Really need to have data from one schema to another: a 1 time thing.

Comment: Can you just create the new table with the DDL the way you want it and then insert from a select?

Comment: @GregPavlik I could, if they are not so heavy ...for some, it might be OK, but for others, takes toooo long in my WH, for tables with millions of rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can still clone your base table w/ primary keys and constraints.  You can then rename the columns in your cloned table which won't affect any associated constraints.  For example:

-- Create a table to use as a foreign key constraint

create or replace table fk_table (id integer primary key);

-- create a base table w/ a primary key, default value and FK constraint

create or replace table basetable (id integer,
dt date default current_date,
fk integer,
primary key (id),
foreign key (fk) references fk_table (id));
-- Clone your table

Create or replace table clone_table clone basetable;

-- Alter the table and rename some of the columns
alter table clone_table rename column id to id_new;
alter table clone_table rename column fk to fk_new;

-- Get the DDL of your new object and confirm the constraints and defaults
-- were preserved

select get_ddl('table','clone_table');